# Difference between Gaussian Distribution and Cauchy Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normal-distribution, cauchy-distribution

I have searched for the above topic but did not have an answer. Can someone please tell me the detailed difference between the multivariate Gaussian Distribution and multivariate Cauchy Distribution? How do they differ in sampling is Estimation of Distribution algorithm for optimisation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution makes it clear that they are extreme cases of a family of distributions.

Comment: The Wiki page did not tell me anything about the difference between Gaussian Distribution and Cauchy. It tells me that Cauchy is a special case of student t distribution. I really want to know the difference between Gaussian and Cauchy in detail.

Comment: As Nick said, the Gaussian is *also* a special case of the t-distribution (a limiting case), though in fact the Cauchy isn't the extreme case in the other direction if one allows non-integer degrees of freedom; I've seen $t_\frac{1}{2}$ used for example. I could write down a hundred differences between the two that one might discern (e.g. a common observation people make is that the Cauchy is heavier-tailed and more peaked). To list every difference you *might* mean could fill a book (and mean your question will be closed). What kind of things do you mean?

Comment: They are graphed side by side in the Wikipedia entry and their equations are given.

Comment: Any difference between Gaussian Distribution and Cauchy, especially in terms of sampling. Preferably the difference on the multivariate type of the two distributions.

Comment: @Lams Please make such additions to your actual question; people shouldn't have to read far down the comments to see what you want. Is this for some subject? The Cauchy doesn't have a mean and has infinite standard deviation; the sampling distribution of the sample mean from a Cauchy is the same as the original individual observations.

Comment: Comparison of the _multivariate_ Gaussian and Cauchy  distributions is possibly covered by one of the more mathematical multivariate books. It's more esoteric than comparing the univariate distributions. Even postulating multivariate Cauchy must be one of the most pessimistic models you can think of. Details aside, sampling from such a distribution is a nightmare.

Comment: @Nick Cox Can you tell me the title of the book? also is there no difference between the multivariate ones? If No difference, then can i know the difference between them in General. Just to have some understanding.

Comment: This question is still too broad in the 'takes a book to answer' sense. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: @Nick I must be missing something: it looks to me like sampling from the multivariate Student t requires little more than drawing a radius from a *t* distribution, rescaling it, applying a random rotation, and multiplying that by an appropriate square root of $\Sigma$.  Why is this a "nightmare"?

Comment: @whuber, well, when you say to be specific, i don't know the specificity of Gaussian and Causchy u talking about. I know multivariate cauchy is the same as student t distribution with degree of freedom 1. Now how does this differ with the multivariate Gaussian. I also know that both have covariance matrix, what is the difference in the covariance estimation? General any difference between the multivariate cauchy and Gaussian?

Comment: @whuber: Jokes sometimes misfire. I meant that sampling from a multivariate Cauchy distribution would be a nightmare in practice for data analysts. The derivations, as you state, clearly are to hand.

Comment: Interesting. one difference between the multivariate Gaussian and cauchy distribution is that cauchy has a heavier tail ans as such one has more chance of sampling in optimisation than Gaussian.this is the only difference in know. Some i am asking experts for other differences other than the one i just said. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: We are struggling, Lams, because there are *infinitely many* differences between these two distributions. Your question is a little bit like "please tell me all the numbers--I know only the number $1,$ so I am asking experts for more numbers."  That's just too vague and broad to take on.  But if you could explain *why* you are comparing the Cauchy and Gaussian distributions, then we might have a chance of focusing our answers on things that matter (much as if, by analogy, you were to explain that you wanted to find all the even prime numbers, rather than just any number at all).

Comment: Sorry for being stupid in my questions. I am trying to know their difference with respect to optimisation, especially on the EDA types. or evolutionary optimisations, say swarm. But lets just say on the Estimation of Distribution Algorithm(EDA) types. What to know their difference in sampling of individuals.

Answer (score 2):

You might need these papers:

1. Multivariate Cauchy EDA Optimisation http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axk/Momodou1.pdf

There is a detailed explanation of the difference between Gaussian & Cauchy distribution in Chapter 2, along with empirical results and other analyses.

2. How effective is Cauchy-EDA in high dimensions? http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axk/Cauchy-cec2016.pdf

Further reading for Cauchy distribution used in EDA published this year.

Hope it helps.